# MySQL JOIN that I can't wrap my head around

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables (two are important and one is just for clarification) that look like this:

**team**

```
_team_ID         name
       1    Blue Team
       2   Green Team
       3   Black Team
```

**game**

```
_game_ID   _team_left_ID   _team_right_ID
       1               1                2
       2               2                1
       3               1                2
```

**game_points**

```
_game_points_ID   _game_ID   _team_ID
              1          1          1
              2          1          1
              3          1          2
              4          1          1
              5          2          2
```

_team_ID is in _team_left_ID or _team_right_ID, depending on what side they started on.

_team_ID in game_points is the team who scored a point. So there needs to be a COUNT() somewhere.

What I want to achieve is to get how many points _team_ID 1 and 2 and got in each game they played against each other and who got the most points.

Basically this:

```
_game_ID   _team_left_ID   _team_right_ID   left_points   right_points   winner
       1               1                2             3              1        1
       2               2                1             1              0        2
       3               1                2             0              0     NULL
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself

Comment: Yes, but I always get the left_points and right_points to the exact same number or I get both of them to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admittedly have not tested this, but I believe this should get you in the right direction.  I'm unsure if the last line of the select will work, but worse case you can just compare left points vs right points to determine the victor.

```
SELECT
game._game_ID,
left_team._team_ID,
right_team._team_ID,
SUM(game_points._team_ID = left_team._team_ID) as left_pts,
SUM(game_points._team_ID = right_team._team_ID) as right_pts,
IF(SUM(game_points._team_ID = left_team._team_ID) = SUM(game_points._team_ID = right_team._team_ID),NULL,IF(SUM(game_points._team_ID = left_team._team_ID) > SUM(game_points._team_ID = right_team._team_ID), left_team._team_ID, right_team._team_ID)) as winner
FROM game
INNER JOIN team as left_team ON left_team._team_ID = game._team_left_ID
INNER JOIN team as right_team ON right_team._team_ID = game._team_right_ID
LEFT JOIN game_points ON game_points._game_ID = game._game_ID
GROUP BY game._game_ID
```

---

Adding final use-case just to flush out the answer.

```
SELECT
game._game_ID,
left_team._team_ID,
right_team._team_ID,
SUM(game_points._team_ID = left_team._team_ID) as left_pts,
SUM(game_points._team_ID = right_team._team_ID) as right_pts,
CASE WHEN SUM(game_points._team_ID = left_team._team_ID) > SUM(game_points._team_ID = right_team._team_ID) THEN left_team._team_ID WHEN SUM(game_points._team_ID = left_team._team_ID) < SUM(game_points._team_ID = right_team._team_ID) THEN right_team._team_ID ELSE NULL END AS winner
FROM game
INNER JOIN team as left_team ON left_team._team_ID = game._team_left_ID
INNER JOIN team as right_team ON right_team._team_ID = game._team_right_ID
LEFT JOIN game_points ON game_points._game_ID = game._game_ID
GROUP BY game._game_ID
```

Comment: That was actually from a previous revision.  I originally joined game_points twice to get it to show correctly.  Then I realized I could do the same thing with 1 join and an aggregate function.  I think I have it right now.

Comment: I think your IF statement needs work.  You are going to compare the number of times the left Team ID comes up with the number of times the right Team ID comes up.  You aren't comparing the points.

Comment: Awesome! That works almost perfectly. Only thing missing is if the score is even, it now shows right_team as winner. But I guess changing it to a CASE  could solve that?

Comment: I changed the IF to a CASE and it worked like a charm for return NULL if there is no winner. Thanks a lot Camway for the help!

Comment: Updated again, couldn't remember case syntax off the top of my head, that would probably be preferable here, instead I added another if statement.  Enjoy. - edit - I say this after immediately after you posted it lol go figure

Comment: `CASE
WHEN SUM(game_points._team_ID = left_team._team_ID) > SUM(game_points._team_ID = right_team._team_ID) THEN left_team._team_ID
WHEN SUM(game_points._team_ID = left_team._team_ID) < SUM(game_points._team_ID = right_team._team_ID) THEN right_team._team_ID 
ELSE NULL 
END AS winner`

Comment: Sorry, I can't vote because it's my first ever post here. But thank you very much for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: We were all there once, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

As far as DB design.... I'm not sure why game_points is a separate table.
It seems to be an unnecessary normalization.  I would have just put the points in the game table with left_team_points and right_team_points fields. "Normalize until it hurts,denormalize until it makes sense."

Since your question is about the join, I left the case statement and the WHERE conditions for you.  (If this is a HW assignment....I'd ask you tag it with the homework tag.)

I also realized you're missing the points field from the game_points table.

This is untested - there may be typos, but I think the logic is sound.

```
SELECT game._game_ID, left_team._team_ID, right_team._team_ID, left_game_points.points, right_game_points.points, <CASE STATEMENT TO DETERMINE WINNER>
FROM game
JOIN team AS left_team ON left_team.id = game._team_left_ID
JOIN team AS right_team ON right_team.id = game._team_right_ID
JOIN game_points AS left_game_points ON left_game_points._game_ID = game._game_ID 
     and left_game_points._team_ID = team._team_ID
JOIN game_points AS right_game_points ON right_game_points._game_ID = game._game_ID 
     and right_game_points._team_ID = team._team_ID
```

Comment: In game_points, it's one line per point. I have a physical button connected and I need to keep track of the time of each point. Sorry, if it wasn't clear.

Comment: ah.  I would suggest including create table statements with your question next time.  FWIW, one row per point also seems like a poor design choice.  why not just increment?  Maybe if you're storing the timestamp of the point or the person who scored it.